# Adding a background image to a SpriteKit project

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, resolution

The iPhone 6 and 6s are supposed to have a 750 x 1334 resolution [[1]](http://iosres.com/), and the screen ratio for every iPhone since the iPhone 5 is 16:9 [[2]](http://www.mycleveragency.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/iphone-screen-size-comparison-v1.1.0.png). So in order to have a background image for an app that fits perfectly, it must have a 16:9 ratio. I'm working on a project using SpriteKit and I want the game to have a wallpaper that covers the back from edge to edge. However, when I run the app on the simulator the background image always gets cropped on the right and left. I've even tried with all sorts of ratios and resolutions. The code for this background on the project is:

```
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backtImage")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the code you posted what is self in 'self.size'.  Is it the SKScene?

Comment: @MrFlynn yes, it's the SKScene

Answer (score 0):

This could happened because your `SKView` don't match with your `SKScene` dimensions.

The sources:

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public enum SKSceneScaleMode : Int {

    case Fill /* Scale the SKScene to fill the entire SKView. */
    case AspectFill /* Scale the SKScene to fill the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some cropping may occur if the view has a different aspect ratio. */
    case AspectFit /* Scale the SKScene to fit within the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some letterboxing may occur if the view has a different aspect ratio. */
    case ResizeFill /* Modify the SKScene's actual size to exactly match the SKView. */
}
```

You can change your code as below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            ...
            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill // <- this is an example

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Comment: no no no, you should never ever set your scene size to your SKView size,  the resizefill does this for you

Comment: Yeah, you have reason, it also can be confuse the OP, I remove it, thank you Knight0fDragon.

Comment: NP,  the only scenario I can see setting a a scene size to the view is in the case of OSX, where we have a window that can resize, and for some reason you want to preserve the scene aspect ratio that you started the app with

Answer (score 0):

If your image is getting cropped on the left and right side (in Portrait)  Then we are dealing with an .AspectFill scale mode, and your aspect for your scene is shorter than the screen resolution.  This is probably happening because the default scene size provided in the template build is a square.  Go into your .sks file, and change the scene size to something in a 9x16 ratio,  and your  problem should be solved

Comment: But this change compromise the iPhone 4s results. The OP can also be choose iPhone project, not universal but you must also consider the 4s device, is still available.

Comment: from this post,  OP does not care about iphone 4,  so my guess is it is acceptable to lose the top and bottom of the image

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: Your answer say: "Go into your .sks file, and change the scene size to something in a 9x16 ratio.." . I don't like to use SKS files to make this changes, I say I prefeer the code, seems to work like the spriteBuilder -Cocos2D,  did you know it?

Comment: Well you really should adopt the model of separating presentation from functionality,  it allows you to redesign the look without having to change code.  But if you want to do code, then when you create your SKScene, you just set the size to a 9:16 size.   `let scene = SKScene(size:CGSizeMake(320,568))`  or in the case of OP:  `CGSizeMake(375,667)`  (Remember we are doing Retina style coding, so we do points not pixels)

Comment: I think we can speaking about separating presentation from functionality when you have to do with a serious strong IDE , full o options not for example the plenty of bugs spriteBuilder or the poor SpriteKit SKS Editor. 
I believe therefore premature this consideration, maybe with Xcode 9, I hope..

Comment: The XCode SKS Editor is fine the way it is presentation wise,  I have designed full levels/stages  using it.  Remember,  this is design only, it shouldn't involve things like animations

Comment: Even the simplest program have a particle effects package demos, or a basilar texture packer editor to optimize your sprites, nothing of them for now..

Comment: ? You can do particle effects in the sks editor,  you create the particle in a separate sks file and reference it in your scene sks

Comment: as for texture packing,  no, most include only a basic form of packing (XCode does this).  This is why programs like TexturePacker exist

Comment: Do you know Embarcadero IDE's?

Comment: LOL :) , it's not pascal, it's visual C++ and Delphi object oriented, anyway, IMHO this is a good IDE, there is also a 3D strong editor, I don't like the languages but this is my personal opinion.

Comment: Delphi is object pascal

Comment: The Delphi language has continued to evolve over the years , there was really very little of Pascal today. Object pascal is also another product that was developed at first time by Apple Computer.

Comment: The original answer didn't work. I want to try your other solution in the 6th comment, but I don't know how to implement it. Virtually all the code of this scene is between the brackets of "class GameScene: SKScene { ... }". My project is mainly based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpDxFnj-bKQ

Comment: that makes no sense,  unless you are manually setting the size somewhere else in code, or not loading the sks file, or not saving the sks file after you change it (Yes you need to verify your file saves and changes), the original answer works

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Then, how do I implement that code? This tutorial is pretty much how I structured my project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpDxFnj-bKQ